# Serial port C++ problem

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, serial-port

I have a problem connecting to any serial port (want to exchange with an Arduino) using c++ on visual studio.

I'm using the [SerialClass](http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Interfacing/CPPWindows) given in the Arduino playground, but can't open an handle to my port. It throws ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND on every try..

I've been testing many other ways of notating the port:

```
"COM1"
"COM1:"
"\\.\COM1"
```

but nothing's working.

The port is availiable on the system, and working fine using Putty or the Arduino IDE. Additionally it isn't blocked by other processes.

I'm using Windows 7 x64, but project is Win32.

The class is constructed with

`serialPort = new Serial((char*)port);`

and the error string shows the right portname.

What I'm doing wrong?

**File opening isn't working, too.**

Comment: you will probably also want to extend that class to be able to modify the ports settings once you fix your error. It currently doesn't have a way to programmatically configure the port, and all settings are hard coded. The data read/sent will possibly not *mesh* with w/e you're trying to connect to. Here is also a good example (RIGHT from MS) on how to utilize their .NET framework which has a serial port class directly available. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx

Comment: If you're looking for an alternative but still using c++, you could try `Qt` and use the open sourced `QextSerialPort` library. I've had some VERY good success using it and it has a very small learning curve, considering most of the examples are easily c/p'able to what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the Answer!

I casted the string using (LPCTSTR), but this wouldn't return a valid string. Had to use

`const WCHAR FileFullPath[] = {L"COM4"} ;`

for conversion.

Answer (score 4):

A good example of others manually using the api to open a serial port is [here](http://www.lookrs232.com/com_port_programming/api_open_port.htm). The relevant part (regarding your question) shows them using the port number as follows:

```
...
CreateFile("\\\\.\\COM1",GENERIC_WRITE
...
```

so it could be `\\\\.\\COM1` instead of the options you have tried.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363198(v=VS.85).aspx Has an example showing that it should be `\\.\COM1` but *usually* \ is a special character, so you have to double the \\ inorder to get the proper character.

Comment: I would try to used windows API directly. What is in the arduino serialclass is quite limiting and will probably not be good enough for what you want to do.  I've gotten the serial class to work using straight `COM1` before but only when I went through and did it myself.

Comment: well I tried with using API directly, but that isn't working, to, I know the class is very limited, but for what I want to do it shoult work nicely. (only want to send about 8 states with no response)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this isnt a driver problem with Windows 7 64 bit ?

Comment: But then it wouldn't work with other programs?! It's doing fine with putty and the Arduino IDE

Comment: Its a long shot, but have you made sure that there isnt an UAC issue, ie. that the development environment not running with admin. privs.

Comment: have started it as admin, too