# read from serial port c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi, serial-port, windows-xp

I have the following C++ code and when I run the program sometimes it works and sometimes it does not!

I think the problem occurs when I try to open the serial port while there is data left to be read.

Sometimes after running this program, it makes Windows XP restart unexpectedly! It does not Blue Screen, it justs restarts.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 to compile it.

```
main()
{
    while(0) { // BIG FAT WARNING: MIGHT SUDDEN REBOOT YOUR MACHINE IF ENABLED
        read_from_serial(_data);
    }
}

bool read_from_serial(octed_string &_data)
{
    HANDLE hSerial;
    hSerial = CreateFile(TEXT("COM2"),
                         GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE,0,0,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,0);

    if (hSerial == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        if (GetLastError() == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
        {
            cout << "1:";
            return false;
        //serialportdoesnotexist.Informuser.
        }
        cout << "2:";
        return false;

        //someothererroroccurred.Informuser.
    }

    DCB dcbSerialParams = {0};
    dcbSerialParams.DCBlength=sizeof(dcbSerialParams);

    if(!GetCommState(hSerial,&dcbSerialParams))
    {
        cout<<"3:";
        return false;
        //errorgettingstate
    }

    dcbSerialParams.BaudRate=CBR_9600;
    dcbSerialParams.ByteSize=7;
    dcbSerialParams.StopBits=ONESTOPBIT;
    dcbSerialParams.Parity=EVENPARITY;

    if (!SetCommState(hSerial,&dcbSerialParams))
    {
        cout<<"4:";
        return false;
        //errorsettingserialportstate
    }

    COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts={0};
    timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout=50;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant=10;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier=10;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant=50;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier=10;

    if (!SetCommTimeouts(hSerial,&timeouts))
    {
        cout<<"5:";
        return false;
        //erroroccureed.Informuser
    }

    const int n=1;

    DWORD dwBytesRead=0;

    char_t tmp_receive[255]={0};

    char_t buff[255];

    int len=255;

    if (!ReadFile(hSerial,tmp_receive,len,&dwBytesRead,NULL))
    {
        cout<<"6:";
        CloseHandle(hSerial);
        return false;
    }

    CloseHandle(hSerial);

    tmp_receive[dwBytesRead+1]=END_OF_STRING;
    string tmp_buff_str=tmp_receive;
    _data.append(tmp_buff_str);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: and this compiles for you? what does your real program look like?

Comment: `sometimes running this program makes my XP os restart!` - wow. I suggest you don't run it. Does it blue-screen? what is the error? anything in the event log? Windows updates?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049/how-do-i-configure-and-communicate-with-a-serial-port

Comment: This program is not compiled. Maybe compiler makes your XP OS restart? Consider using another compiler.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104915/serial-port-c-problem

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810467.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568782/baudrate-serial-windows-port

Comment: And the prettiest yet: http://www.robbayer.com/files/serial-win.pdf

Comment: i use vs2010 to compile it. this program is written to read from serial port. no blue screen just rebooting!.

Comment: Throw away the adapter.  Get another one with a better driver.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in the debugger to find out at which point the system reboots? Is it opening the device? Setting the timeouts? Reading? It sounds like a driver/device issue, as Hans suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Cause

I have a suspicion that your program is crashing on this line

```
tmp_receive[dwBytesRead+1]=END_OF_STRING;
```

You defined the `tmp_receive` array with `255` elements, which makes the possible indexes `0` to `254`. You then initialized `len` to `255`. If there are 255 bytes available to read on the call to `ReadFile(...)`, then `dwBytesRead` will be equal to `255` and the line I mentioned above will effectively be as follows, and would mean you're attempting to write to memory outside of the scope of the `tmp_receive` array.

```
tmp_receive[256] = END_OF_STRING;
```

As for the rebooting, I don't know for sure, but maybe your program is causing a system crash when it attempts to write to invalid memory and you have Windows XP configured to reboot instead of displaying a [BSOD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Screen_of_Death).

---

### Solutions

In order to keep your program from crashing I see that you have 2 options. I can't say which one is better since I don't know what the format of the data you're expecting to receive is, so you will have to analyize the outcomes of each option and decide for yourself.

**Option #1**

Use an element count of `257` when defining the `tmp_receive` array.

**Option #2**

Subtract 2 from `len` when making the call to `ReadFile(...)`

```
if (!ReadFile(hSerial,tmp_receive,len-2,&dwBytesRead,NULL))
```

---

### Additional Information

- Have a look at the MSDN documentation on [`ReadFile(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more information on the behaviour of the `ReadFile(...)` Windows API.
- If you would like to learn more about how strings are stored in memory, I would suggest having a look at the [Character Sequences](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/ntcs/) article on [www.cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com).

Comment: Also, you don't need to declare tmp_buf, you can just do _data.append(tmp_receive)

[http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/append/](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/append/)